# MS Access - Update and Inner Join with Multiple Rows

Tags: ms-access, sql-update, inner-join

I found answer for this problem foe SQL Server but not MS Access.

Table NE:

```
IP           | Status | Peer
-----------------------------
10.10.10.1   | 0      | null
10.20.1.5    | 0      | null
```

Table Peer:

```
IP           | Peer             | Status | Flap_Count
------------------------------------------------------
10.10.10.1   | 10.100.2.3       | 0      | 0
10.10.10.1   | 10.200.1.1       | 1      | 5
10.10.10.1   | 10.50.100.7      | 10     | 9
10.10.10.1   | 10.1.1.1         | 10     | 7 
10.20.1.5    | 10.20.20.7       | 10     | 5
10.20.1.5    | 10.2.2.10        | 5      | 2
```

Selection Rule

> get record from the biggest Status **AND** biggest Flap_Count

Desired result:

```
IP           | Status | Peer
-----------------------------
10.10.10.1   | 10     | 10.50.100.7
10.20.1.5    | 10     | 10.20.20.7
```

Sometimes this query works and sometimes it fails:

```
Update NE
Inner join (Select * from Peer Order by Status Desc, Flap_Count Desc) Q
On Q.IP = NE.IP
Set NE.Status = Q.Status, NE.Peer = Q.Peer
Where NE.Status = 0
```

That query pops up a notification (for example) that 3 rows will be affected for `IP 10.10.10.1`. Which one will be kept?

When I change `Order by Status Desc` to `Order by Status Asc` the result does not change.

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]. [ask] [Help] Why didn't the MS Server answer help? Either don't mention it or explain what the technique was & why it didn't help.

Comment: Data sample shows record with highest Status also has highest Flap_Count for each IP. Will that always be the case?

Comment: Yes @June7. By the way, your updated solution that has been deleted is working and did not make ms access crash. You can update it again for others that have similar problem. Thanks

Comment: I realized the second approach depends on same record having the highest values for both Status and Flap_Count. Since you say that will always be the case, I will include it.

Comment: Actually in my real table i got error "operation must use an updateable query" then I add DISTINCTROW in "update DISTINCTROW RAN ..."

Comment: See revised answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need a unique identifier field in Peer table - an autonumber will serve.

Do not see that NE table is even needed to produce the desired output.

```
SELECT * FROM Peer WHERE ID IN (
   SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM Peer AS Dup WHERE Dup.IP = Peer.IP 
   ORDER BY Dup.Status DESC, Dup.Flap_Count DESC, Dup.ID DESC);
```

But if you must UPDATE NE:

```
UPDATE NE 
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT * FROM Peer WHERE ID IN (
        SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM Peer AS Dup WHERE Dup.IP = Peer.IP 
        ORDER BY Dup.Status DESC, Dup.Flap_Count, Dup.ID DESC)) AS Q1 
ON NE.IP = Q1.IP SET NE.Status = [q1].[Status], NE.Peer = [q1].[Peer];
```

Unfortunately, correlated subquery can perform poorly with large dataset, even crashing.

Here is alternate approach that does not need unique ID field. It should return one record for each IP if two assumptions are true:

1. same record has highest values for both Status and Flap_Count for each IP
2. Status and Flap_Count will always be unique pairs within each IP group

```
SELECT Peer.* FROM Peer INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Peer.IP, Max(Peer.Status) AS MS, Max(Peer.Flap_Count) AS MF
    FROM Peer
    GROUP BY Peer.IP) AS Q1 
ON Peer.IP = Q1.IP AND Peer.Status = Q1.MS AND Peer.Flap_Count = Q1.MF;
```

An UPDATE action SQL cannot directly use an aggregate (GROUP BY) query as data source, however, I still don't see need for NE table.

Comment: Using this code for more than 100K rows force ms access crash. Dou you have any other advice?

Comment: If Status value is not repeated for each IP value, try an aggregate query: `SELECT IP, Max(Status) AS MS FROM Peer GROUP BY IP;`. Join that query to Peer with compound link on IP and Status fields.

Comment: No Luck, The status are not unique for each IP

Comment: Yet you provide sample data showing it is. Edit your question to show more representative sample and provide rules for data selection. What decision steps would you follow to manually select a record?

Comment: Thank you for the advise. I have updated the table Peer and Selection rule.

Comment: I think I know about what you suggest in comment above, I'll check if it work

Comment: But if you  have solution kindly please to share