# MS Access join with only the max row per item in primary table

Tags: sql, ms-access, one-to-many

I need to perform a join on a one to many table, but I only want to join on the row with the max value per row on my primary table.

## tableA

| productId | productName |
| --- | --- |
| EXAM-001 | A test product |
| LAME-001 | Something else |
| EXAM-002 | Another thing |

## tableB

| id | productId | someValue | user |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | EXAM-001 | 9001 | Alex |
| 2 | EXAM-001 | 8000 | Sheila |
| 3 | LAME-001 | 100 | Alex |

## Desired output from query

| productId | productName | topSomeValue | user |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EXAM-001 | A test product | 9001 | Alex |
| LAME-001 | Something else | 100 | Alex |
| EXAM-002 | Another thing | null | null |

## Example query that works in sqlite

```sql
SELECT tableA.productId, tableA.productName, tableB.someValue AS topSomeValue, tableB.user
FROM tableA
LEFT JOIN tableB
    ON tableA.productId = tableB.productId
    AND tableB.id = (
        SELECT tableB.id
        FROM tableB
        WHERE tableB.productId = tableA.productId
        ORDER BY tableB.someValue DESC
        LIMIT 1
    )
```

The above query works in SQLite but does not work in MS Access SQL. I have researched the problem over several days and have hit a brick wall.

What would be the equivalent in **MS Access SQL**?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MS Access - Update and Inner Join with Multiple Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74084292/ms-access-update-and-inner-join-with-multiple-rows)

Comment: An IN >_< wow I'll give that a try in the morning. I found another solution too but I am not a fan of it, will update this with that in the morning also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me with the given example:

```
SELECT sel.productId, sel.productName, sel.TopSomeValue, TableB.user 
FROM TableB 
RIGHT JOIN 
    (SELECT TableA.productId, TableA.productName, tb_max.TopSomeValue 
     FROM TableA 
     LEFT JOIN 
         (SELECT productId, MAX(someValue) AS TopSomeValue 
         FROM TableB 
         GROUP BY productId) AS tb_max
     ON tb_max.productId = TableA.productId) AS sel 
ON (sel.TopSomeValue = TableB.someValue) AND (sel.productId = TableB.productId);
```